# count the number of occurences for each hour in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

First, sorry for my English who may be poor, I hope you will understand me

I do not see how to recover my object count per hour.
I hope you can help me find out more about my question.

I have a **mission object** that contains a **mission list** that each have as attribute
a **STRING name** and a **STRING time** (hhmmss format)

here is an example :

0 : name1 102101

1 : name2 102801

2 : name3 104801

3 : name4 110501

4 : name5 120301

I wish I could make an array allowing me to count **the number of missions for each hour**

In this example I would have :

10 => 3

11 => 1

12 => 1

I do not know if you see what I would like to get :)

If you ever have small tracks I'm interested

Thank you for reading me !

I wish you a good evening

Comment: Did you try anything?, why can't you take the first 2 characters of the time stamp, put it in a HashMap, where key is the hour and value is the count on how many times it appeared.

Comment: Will creating an array with size 12 and increase the counter at the i-th entry of the array if the new mission you read starts at hour i, will solve your issue?

Comment: Hey and thanks for the reply. I ask the question because i don't know for chat i have to loop. And yes @Juseeth i'll do a substring on the 2 first caractere

Comment: @AntoineOffroy Instantiate a HashMap with String as key and Integer as value, loop over objects, for each object split string until first 2 characters, then check if the hour is already in the map, if yes, then increment the value for the hour key or else set the value to the key as 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

- As the comments mentioned, you may want to use a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) with `String` keys reflecting the *hour* and `Integer` values for the *count* (missions per hour).
- Since you're dealing with **hours, meaning that you have a maximum of 24 of them**, you can also replace the `HashMap` with an `Array` of 24 items.

## The `Mission` class

Basically, all is needed here is a *getter* for the `time` attribute. If you feel fancy, you can also add a `getHour` which will return the hour instead of the whole `time` string.

```
class Mission {
    private String name;
    private String time;
    Mission(String name, String time) {
        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;
    }

    String getHour() {
        // This gives us the 2 first characters into a String - aka the "hour"
        return time.substring(0, 2);
    }
}
```

## Using the `HashMap`

We want to keep the count per hour in a `HashMap`. So we'll iterate over the `missionsList` and for each item, we'll get its `count`, then we'll increment it.

If the `hour` is not in the `HashMap` yet, we would normally receive a `null`. To handle that with minimal boilerplate, we'll use the [`getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) method. We can call it like this `map.getOrDefault("10", 0)`. This will return the *missions count of hour 10*, and if that count doesn't exist yet (which means we didn't add it to the map yet) we will receive `0` instead of `null`. The code will look like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // This will built our list of missions
    List<Mission> missionsList = Arrays.asList(
            new Mission("name1", "102101"),
            new Mission("name2", "102801"),
            new Mission("name3", "104801"),
            new Mission("name4", "110501"),
            new Mission("name5", "120301")
    );

    // This map will keep the count of missions (value) per hour (key)
    Map<String, Integer> missionsPerHour = new HashMap<>();

    for (Mission mission : missionsList) {
        // Let's start by getting the hour,
        // this will act as the key of our map entry
        String hour = mission.getHour();

        // Here we get the count of the current hour (so far).
        // This is the "value" of our map entry
        int count = missionsPerHour.getOrDefault(mission.getHour(), 0);

        // Here we increment it (by adding/replacing the entry in the map)
        missionsPerHour.put(hour, count + 1);
    }

    // Once we have the count per hour,
    // we iterate over all the keys in the map (which are the hours).
    // Then we simply print the count per hour
    for (String hour : missionsPerHour.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(String.format(
            "%s\t=>\t%d", hour, missionsPerHour.get(hour)
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Your solution helped me to progress, I did not think directly about hashmap